# How to apply a template for every screen in sketchflow?

Tags: xaml, sketchflow

How do i apply a common template to every screen in a sketchflow project.

I basically want some common navigation on the top and side and don’t want to have to draw it on every screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your common UI as a component screen.  It can then be used in as many other screens as you like.

You can either create a new component screen in the map, or select some content already on a screen, and turn that into a new component screen using the context menu on those items.